# How to run exact generic test in dbt by name

Tags: sql, dbt

For example, I would like to run the test 'date_validation' written by myself and located in folder 'generic' , where generic tests are located.

What operation can I use to run this particular test where it is mentioned?

I found this operation but it runs all generic tests : `dbt test --select test_type:generic`

Answer (score 1):

```
dbt test --select generic.date_validation
```

- `generic.date_validation` tells dbt to run only `date_validation` test in `generic` folder.

Comment: I have after that: [WARNING]: Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args

Comment: I made a mistake in the first response, as `--select` only accepts the tag/name and not the full path. please try `dbt test --models generic --select date_validation`

Comment: I have the same:  Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dbt test --select "generic,test_name:date_validation"
```

Here more about node selection methods:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).